# Could not fetch all href link using BeautifulSoup module using python2.6

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month,     born.day))
```

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: Please edit the question, list down what you have done and then point out to the place where you are not able to proceed.